# How to check ftp connection logs on CentOS?

Tags: ftp

My website is running on Linux CentOS digitalocean. Is there any way to check ftp connection logs or currently opened ftp connections? I would like to make sure nobody else uses the ftp username.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.

The location of the logs depend on the service you're using but usually the location is `/var/log` .

Let's say you use proftpd service... you'll find its logs in `/var/log/proftpd/proftpd.log` and for other FTPd services in their respective paths in `/var/log`.

It's possible that your configuration saves logs in a different path than the default one.

In order to find which FTPd service your server runs, run:

```
netstat -plunt | grep ftp
```

This will show you which process holds the FTP port and then you'll know the service name.

Next thing is to locate that service's logs.